# Paying all at once or paying in installments on new purchase?

Tags: purchase, installment-sale

I just wonder what would be best way of paying when we make new purchase.

Is it paying money at once or in installments?

Comment: are you buying groceries, a car, or a house?  What is the time frame to save up the whole purchase price?  Interest rate?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, generally for consumer goods it is advisable to pay money in one go and avoid paying installments as there are charges for it.